# Ordinal Arithmetic: Why is ε0 = ω^ω^ω^ω...

Tags: ordinals

In other words, in this notation, why not continue the pattern of ω+ω, ω*ω, ω^ω, ω↑↑ω, and so on, using ω↑↑ω instead of ε0? Is there any reason for ending that pattern with exponentiation, rather than using tetration and other super-operators? Does ω↑↑ω even have the same meaning as ε0?

Comment: Since $\epsilon_1$ doesn't look like anything pretty in Knuth up-arrow notation.

Comment: Well, depending on how you define $\epsilon_1$ of course... but the end result is that writing $\epsilon_0=\omega\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ implies something about how you get to $\epsilon_0$, but this depends on how you defined it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The principal reason is that the $\epsilon_0$ notation can be used to extend much, *much* further, because Knuth up-arrow notation handles infinities poorly. One way of writing $\epsilon_1$ is as $\epsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$, and then $\epsilon_2 = (\epsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega)\uparrow\uparrow\omega$, and so on. I think we could define $\epsilon_{\omega}$ as $\omega\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ (but don't quote me on that one).

But what about $\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}$? That would take $\epsilon_0$-many up-arrows. And then $\epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}}$ is even worse. So, to summarize: we *could* use Knuth up-arrow notation, but we had to start using the epsilon notation somewhere, so we started here.

Comment: I suspected something along those lines, but then why not set ϵ0 to an earlier fixed point, like ω^2 (or am I misunderstanding the concept, would ω^ω be the more natural equivalent). It makes sense that Knuth up-arrow notation is a bit clunky and inefficient, so you need to switch to the ϵ ordinals at some point.

Comment: @user424667 $\epsilon_0$ is a fixed point of exponentiation specifically - there are no earlier fixed points. You could talk about fixed points of multiplication, but those are just limit powers of $\omega$. Since it's so easy to characterize those fixed points, and since exponents are relatively familiar compared to $\uparrow\uparrow$, it makes the most sense to use $\epsilon$ for exponentials. Also, $\epsilon$ numbers are particularly significant to proof theory, so it makes sense to use special notation for them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand now.

Comment: Not so sure I agree that one should always use the traditional Cantorian notation based upon exponentiation, even if it is true that ε0 is the first fixed point os the infinite sequence of larger ordinals.  One doesn't have to use Knuth's up arrow notation, -- which I for one have never liked -- to get to more rapidly compounding limit ordinals.  One can also use the very simply notation [x,y,z] where x is the ordinal to be compounded, y is the operation of compounding to be utilized, and z is the number of compoundings to be applied.

Comment: Thus, [2,n,2] is always = 4 fo all n, while [3,3,2] = 27 and [2,4,3] = [2,3,4] = 2^2^2^2 {calucated from right to left] = 2^16 or 65,536. When one gets to the infinite ordinals one works the same way, so [ω,4,ω] = ε0, while [ω, ω, ω] denotes some ordinal so large that we have no standard way of addressing it with our current notation systems.  And then, of course, there are things like [ε0, 4, ε0], i.e. an exponential stack of ε0s, ε0 long, or [ε0, ε0, ε0] etc. ... and we are just getting started!

Comment: How about [Γω, Γω, Γω] οr similar compoundings "forever and way beyond" all the largest well-known, still countable, ordinals as well? And only then we might pass on to UNcountable things like [ω1, ω1, ω1] whatever such a monstrosity might be!

Comment: It thus seems to me that there are notations flexible enough to treat most large countable ordinals. The problem is that most mathematicians, even set theorists,  seem to find it hard to think much beyond exponentiation, or at best tetration, when considering compounding operations.  But such operations can clearly be defined not only to the 'nth" degree, but indeed to any degree however large, even if that still leaves the huge problem of attempting to WORK with such huge ordinals.

Comment: @WdFusroy "It thus seems to me that there are notations flexible enough to treat most large countable ordinals." This is understandable, but it's an incorrect perception. Using the notation you suggest, consider the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = [\alpha,\alpha,\alpha]$. This ordinal is still countable, and in a strong sense "most" countable ordinals are larger than it. Indeed, it is straightforward to show that in any language with only countably many symbols, "most" countable ordinals cannot be expressed.

Comment: @WdFusroy And since there are few if any applications known for ordinals like $[\epsilon_0,4,\epsilon_0]$, and we have to resort to abstract "naming" anyway, we might as well start before the operations start getting exotic.

Comment: @Reese Thanks so much for your comments on my comments! Just as you say, it is no more possible to denominate all of the infinite limit ordinals than it is to name all of the finite natural numbers.  So the question is really only one of finding the simplest notation system to go out as far as possible. The notation I mentioned is, of course, parasitic on the conventional Cantorian notation to a good extent, -- though that could conceivably be eliminated. Certainly this notation could go out beyond the current systems, but this would only be of use if we learned how to work with such beasts.

Comment: Even a relatively small ordinal, say, [2, 6,ω] -- where 2 is substituted for the initial ω since the substitution makes no difference I'm told -- is already so huge that it is very difficult to break it down into exponential form. [ω, ω, ω] is thus already a truly huge limit ordinal. [The ω in the operational place ensures that.] So things like [Γε0, Γε0, Γε0] would obviously be vastly beyond the Feferman-Schuette ordinal which is often the last denominated uncollapsed oridnal today. Your first ordinal such that a = [α, α, α] is interesting. But I'm not sure such an α exists. Is there a proof?

Comment: Two last things. I'm not certain that [ω, ω, ω], unlike [ω, n, ω] for all n in N, is still countable, precisely because it has the smallest limit ordinal, ω, in the middle, telling the compounding operations have now become infinite. Nor do I know how to go about proving that it is or is not still countable. ... I got interested in all this, btw, because I am trying to determine which ordinals lie between ω and ω1, the first uncountable ordinal, and limit ordinal of all the countables. I want to know that because I want to determine how the Beth series continues past Beth[ω] to Beth[ω1].

Comment: @WdFusroy You haven't defined $[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$ for limit $\beta$, but the conventional way would be to take it to be the limit of $[\alpha,\delta,\gamma]$ for $\delta < \beta$. In that case, $[\omega,\omega,\omega]$ is the limit of countably many countable ordinals and is automatically countable. As for the existence of the $\alpha$ I described: it's a well-known fact that any continuous function on the ordinals has a fixed point. By projecting $[x,y,z]$ into continuous components, you can argue that $[x,x,x]$ must likewise have a fixed point.

Comment: @Reese Thanks again for your latest comment!  I agree that "the conventional way would be to take it to be the limit of [α,δ,γ] for δ<β." That is what I had in mind.  I also agree that "[ω,ω,ω] is the limit of countably many countable ordinals and is automatically countable." I suspected that before, but the omega operations limit made me wonder whether it were still true.

Comment: You also state; "it's a well-known fact that any continuous function on the ordinals has a fixed point. By projecting [x,y,z] into continuous components, you can argue that [x,x,x] must likewise have a fixed point."  That I don't follow. Surely [2, 1, ω] has no fixed point, or else you are using the latter term differently than I am. How then could the infinitely "faster' functions describing [α,α,α] ever = α? I am obviously not understanding your "fixed point" usage. But I am quite willing to learn how you are using the term.  Is it the same principle as in Beth[α] = α for some large α?